# R GGPLOT2 lapply and function not finding object?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I hope I can get a contextual clue as to what may be wrong here without providing data frame, but can if necessary, but ultimately I want to utilize lapply to create multiple boxplots across multiple Ys and same X, but get the following error, but Termed is definitely in my CMrecruitdat data.frame:

Error in aes_string(x = Termed, y = RecVar, fill = Termed) : 
  object 'Termed' not found

```
RecVar <- CMrecruitdat[,c("Req.Open.To.System.Entry", "Req.Open.To.Hire", "Tenure")]

BP <- function (RecVar){
  require(ggplot2)
  ggplot(CMrecruitdat, aes_string(x=Termed, y=RecVar, fill=Termed))+
     geom_boxplot()+
     guides(fill=false)
}

lapply(RecVar, FUN=BP)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `aes_string`, you should pass strings rather than vectors and use strings for all your fields.

```
RecVar <- CMrecruitdat[,c("Termed", "Req.Open.To.System.Entry", "Req.Open.To.Hire", "Tenure")]

BP <- function (RecVar){
  require(ggplot2)
  ggplot(RecVar, aes_string(x="Termed", y=RecVar, fill="Termed"))+
     geom_boxplot()+
     guides(fill=false)
}

lapply(names(RecVar), FUN=BP)
```

Comment: Nope. Because `aes()` expects symbols and it won't evaluate those parameters. You're better off sticking with `aes_string()` if you want to write functions that call `ggplot`.

Comment: It actually worked with aes...but didn't read the names into the Y axis instead it just repeated "RecVar" for the three, but it definitely created the three.

Comment: I've updated and tried your way and it gives me the same error

Comment: Nevermind, we are using strings and needed quotations.